# Use node-fluent-ffmpeg to do video overlay

Tags: video, ffmpeg, overlay

I'm tring to use node-fluent-ffmpeg to overlay video.

```
proc.addOption('-vf', '[in] pad=2*iw:ih [left0]', 'movie=' + sourceVideo + '[input0]', '[left0][input0] overlay=960:0 [out]');
```

Comment: First; how are you "trying to use" node-fluent? Show us code that compiles and exhibits the problem. Second, what does “not working” mean? It shows an error? What is the error message?

Comment: Sorry. I am using fluent-ffmpeg to encode a source video then double it's size using padding so that I can then overlay a copy of the video over the padded area. A video is being created but it does not have the overlay.

Comment: Seeing the actual ffmpeg console output would be useful. You want the same video input to be both sources for the the overlay?

Comment: Yes I want to show the same video. There is no console output. Node does not show any errors.
var proc = new ffmpeg({
           source: sourceVideo.mp4,
           timeout: 0
}); 
proc.addOption('-vf', '[in] pad=2*iw:ih [left0]', 'movie=' + sourceVideo.mp4+ '[input0]', '[left0][input0] overlay=960:0[out]');
proc.saveToFile("outputVideo.mp4", function() {
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A typical ffmpeg command using the same input as both sources for the `overlay` video filter:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter_complex "[0:v]pad=iw*2:ih[bg];[bg][0:v]overlay=W/2" -codec:a copy output.mkv
```

[image: side by side]

- Note that if you had two different inputs you should include the [`setpts`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setpts_002c-asetpts) filter and the `shortest` option as shown in the examples in the [`overlay` documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Examples-51).
- No need to use the [`movie`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#movie-1) multimedia source filter when you use `-filter_complex`.
- The audio is [stream copied](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) with `-codec:a copy` instead of re-encoded.

This can be probably translated to your script as:

```
proc.addOption('-filter_complex', '[0:v]pad=iw*2:ih[bg];[bg][0:v]overlay=W/2');
```